# Nesting level too deep when looping through matrix blocks

Tags: templating, matrix, forloop, error, loop

I'm running into a nesting level error when looping through matrix blocks, and I can't quite figure out what the problem is.

The problem arises when I use a variable to track the type of the previous element in the matrix. I want to be able to know within the sub-template that an element is the n<sup>th</sup> of the same type (for adding a container around some matrix block types to group them).

If I replace line 7 below with, eg. `{% set n = (element.type == 'product') ? n + 1 : 0 %}` (ie. a named element type rather than a variable) it works as expected, but as soon as I compare `element.type` to `prevElementType` I get a `Fatal error: Nesting level too deep - recursive dependency?` error. Some of the partial templates that may be included in the loop check `prevElementType`, but none of them modify it, so I can't see what's causing the recursion. I'd be grateful for any help with this.

```
{% if entry.contentBlocks is not empty %}
  {% set prevElementType = false %}

  {% for element in entry.contentBlocks %}

  {# Let's use a counter for multiple blocks of the same type: #}
  {% set n = (element.type == prevElementType) ? n + 1 : 1 %}

  {# Include the partial for this block: #}
  {% include "_pageelements/" ~ element.type|lower %}

  {# Track this element's type for the next iteration: #}
  {% set prevElementType = element.type %}

  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: (Incidentally, I can get around the problem by explicitly listing the element types that might need a container - eg. `if (element.type == 'product' or element.type == ' ... ')`, but ideally I'd still like to be able to track "nth of type" generically, so I'd like to get to the bottom of this)

Comment: What does `{{dump(element.type)}}` show you? If it's not a simple string, you may want to use `element.type.handle`

Comment: Oh gosh, you're absolutely right. Because the comparison of `element.type` to a string worked, I assumed `element.type` was itself a simple string. If you put the above comment as an answer, I'll mark it accepted. Thanks!

Comment: Twig has an `===` operator for when you want to avoid those type coercions: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/sameas.html

Comment: Ah, thanks - that's also good to know. I always use `===` when writing code, but hadn't realised that option was available in Twig.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`element.type` is not a simple string (add `{{dump(element.type)}}` to your loop to see this). What you should use is `element.type.handle`. So the assignment is:

```
{% set prevElementType = element.type.handle %}
```

And the comparison (now of two strings, so no recursion) is:

```
element.type.handle == prevElementType
```