# Nesting level too deep - recursive dependency?

Tags: yii, sort

I've got a page with a couple of levels of loops. It takes a section of speakers, groups them by state, and then loops through the states, and then loops through speakers in that state. It's not too complex so I wouldn't expect to see an error like "nesting too deep".

**Here's (a reduction of) the code:**

```
{% set speakersByState = speakers|group(s => s.state.one().slug) %}
{% for state, speakers in speakersByState %}
  <ul>
    {% for speaker in speakers|sort %}
      <li>{{ speaker.title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out, with help from a GitHub thread or too. It appeared that using the `sort` filter on an array of objects was problematic. I was able to fix this by sorting the keys in `speakers` instead of directly sorting `speakers`.

**Working code**:

```
{% for speakerKey in speakers|keys|sort %}
  {% set speaker = speakers[speakerKey] %}

  <li>{{ speaker.title }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm not 1000% sure *exactly* what was breaking, but I think by using `|sort` on a collection of objects, PHP ended up recursively looping through the `speakers` array in an attempt to sort it.

Here are some related threads that I pieced together to guess that `|sort` was the problem:

- [Nesting level too deep when looping through matrix blocks](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10294/nesting-level-too-deep-when-looping-through-matrix-blocks)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834791/fatal-error-nesting-level-too-deep-recursive-dependency
- https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/5794